# Hibernate's @JoinFormula to retrieve a list of childs causes ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I runned into a problem that happens when trying to use the `@JoinFormula` annotation on a `@OneToMany` property of an entity.

I need to map the childs of a entity using a custom join (for now, let's say, all the childs, just to simplify the upcoming example).

### My attempt

In this case, what makes sense to me is to do:

**Approach A**

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    @JoinFormula(value="(SELECT * FROM child)")
    private Set<Child> childs;
    
    //getters, setters...
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne()
    private Parent parent;

    //Ids, getters, setters...
}
```

So, this code works well when no Join Formula is annotated, but, when it is, i get this while booting my Spring JPA application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate collection persister org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column
```

Basically, I want to do [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/) but without returning only one child, being able to return a list of childs.

### My research

- The solution seems to be [moving the @JoinFormula to the @ManyToOne side and make the @OneToMany bidirectional](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-use-the-hibernate-joinformula-annotation-with-a-onetomany-jpa-association/1461/2?u=carlos_lopez), which would be something like:

**Approach B**

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Child> childs;

    //Ids, getters, setters...
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinFormula(value="(SELECT * FROM parent)") //I guess you don't have to change the FROM clause. Tried both anyway.
    private Parent parent;

    //Ids, getters, setters...
}
```

- But that throws a similar exception:

  ```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column
  ```
- According to [the Hibernate's team](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044758&view=next) it's a problem with a Spring Boot related class.
- I did open a [issue on Spring Boot's GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18533), and they replicated the example above without any Spring Boot class involved and still happens the same exception, so it is definitely **not a Spring problem** as they pointed.

### Conclusion.

Personally I conclude that [hibernate ignores this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12997).

Comment: The conclusion that it is a Spring Boot issue is not really clear from the error. Yes eventually the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` will show up because that is what bootstraps the hibenate based `EntityManagerFactory` which throws the classcast exception. I suspect you get the exact same error when removing Spring Boot from the matter and bootstrap hibernate/jpa yourself.

Comment: They replicated your error without hibernate, hence it is an hibernate issues. Have you tried replicating it yourself without Spring? As the test is now in the issue tracker you should be able to reproduce it yourself fairly easy. Also try with different versions of hibernate maybe it works on an older version (or newer).

Comment: @M.Deinum They replicated "Approach A" which we alredy know it's supposed to fail in Hibernate, what apparently solves the problem and only crashes with Spring Boot is the "Approach B". I edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Looking at the `Account` sample that is just uni-directional and contains a partial query in `@JoinFormula`. The `Post` sample is also uni-directional as the `Comment` has a relation to the `Post` but not the other way around. The `latestComment` is only a readonly part of the `Post` entity. Also looking at the `Post` sample the query returns an `id` and not all the columns. All in all I believe the expression of Steve Ebersole and the fact that [`HHH-12997`](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12997) isn't resolved what you want to achieve isn't supported but Hibernate.

Comment: Again have you actually tried approach B without Spring Boot... They replicated your issue with plain Hibernate (they didn't have to but they did). Ofcourse they aren't going to try to replicate all the permuations of the issue. Hence my question was have you tried it yourself, given that the code is now there that should be quite easy to do.